# Override Delete command in context menu on each view

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to override the delete command when I do a right-click on a package folder for exemple.
First I add an extension point (handler on org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete) to use my delete class on different cases and it work great when I press Delete button or when I go to Edit->Delete.
But when I use context menu, original delete action is use and I don't know how to add a handler on right-click command.I create a new command in context menu, My Delete, and I work well but I have 2 delete in the context menu.
I want to override original delete with mine.

I hope I can find an Eclipse RCP expert here to help me.
Thanks.

Sincerely,
Arnaud.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override that delete in the context menu.  The explorer uses an Action to put it there, and that's just a step up from an SWT.Selection event (not tied into the commands/keybinding system).